# What is the max. length of string for GP output?

Tags: geoprocessing, xml

I have an XML as the output of Geo-processing tool. I am keeping it as a file right now but another developer wants it as return value. So what is the maximum possible length of this String output? Is this variable type or fixed type based on MS terminology?- Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With XML technologies, the maximum length of a string will usually be very high - typically limited either to something like 2^32 characters or the amount of memory available. But the detail depends on what products are in your toolchain.